# a template to conjugate matrices, vectors and numbers using Eigen

Tags: c++, templates, eigen

I have three functions implementing the same operation for complex matrices, vectors and numbers.

```
Eigen::Matrix<std::complex<double>,2,2> bc(int sign, Eigen::Matrix<std::complex<double>,2,2> in) {
    return sign == -1 ? in.conjugate() : in;
}
Eigen::Matrix<std::complex<double>,2,1> bc(int sign, Eigen::Matrix<std::complex<double>,2,1> in) {
    return sign == -1 ? in.conjugate() : in;
}
std::complex<double> bc(int sign, std::complex<double> in) {
    return sign == -1 ? conj(in) : in;
}
```

I want to make the code shorter by using templates, but I can't since std::complex doesn't have a conjugate() member function. I don't want to use intermediaries like 1x1 complex matrix because then i would need to call .value() everywhere.
What can i do in this case?

Comment: This looks short and clear enough tbh.

Comment: I have tried to use Eigen::Matrix<std::complex<double>,1,1> but it doesn't fit my needs, it's a clumsy solution

Comment: Is it okay if you just combine the first two overloads into one and remain the third one as it is?

Comment: make bc a function template:
template <Element, Rows, Cols>
Eigen::Matrix<std::complex<Element>, Rows, Cols> bs(sign,...)
That saves one function. 

For the complex<double> case you still have to overload. if constexpr has been mentioned, which might save you one function. But that does provide little to no additional shortening

Comment: @MohammedLi Element, Rows, Cols, has not been declared

Comment: @Peter. true. But (evidently? just assuming) you know you have to add a typename or class before template parameters :)

Comment: @Peter As done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77807595/12002570).

Answer (score 1):

You can combine the first two overloads into a single function template using *non-type template parameter* for the rows/columns and type parameter for the type, as shown below:

```
template<typename T, std::size_t M, std::size_t N> Eigen::Matrix<std::complex<T>,M,N> bc(int sign, Eigen::Matrix<std::complex<double>,M,N> in)
{
    return sign == -1 ? in.conjugate() : in;
}
```